# Illustrated children’s fantasy book, including a giant eagle and a phoenix having a battle

Tags: books, story-identification

As a child in the 80s, my aunt gave me an illustrated fantasy book full of short stories. It was an 8-1/2 by 11 book, IIRC, and the illustrations were in full color, taking up half of the page space. The one I remember most vividly involved a giant eagle and a phoenix having some sort of battle, but there were a few other stories, too. The illustrations were fantastic (or at least I thought to at the time), and I've never seen another copy of this book since. I know my details are thin, but I'm hoping someone might remember what this book is.

Comment: What language/nationality was it? Was it new in the 80s, or even older? Any characters or names you remember?

Comment: Please add more information, as it stands, the details are a bit too vague.

Comment: This book was in English, and it was new in the 80's as far as I am aware. I can't remember much else about it. I know that this is a bit of a stretch, but figured it wouldn't hurt to ask. I've seen people identify all kinds of crazy books on here with just a few details. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it perhaps [The Kincaid's Book of Wizards, Giants, Trolls and Magic](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/928970.The_Kincaid_s_Book_Of_Wizards_Giants_Trolls_And_Magic)?

I had that one during the same time frame you're talking about and a lot of the details seems to match.

[image]

Comment: Holy smokes, that's it!